# How to remove a text "-Wordpress" from may whatsapp link sharing

Tags: php, html, whatsapp, sharing

When I click  on my sharing link to whatsapp it'll always with Access "Sinte Name" - Wordpress.

How to remove this text 'wordpress'.

```
<?php
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
?>

<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo current_url(); ?>"  data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Link</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: please add output url

Comment: $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
$formatted_url = str_replace("-Wordpress", "", $current_url);

Comment: Acess < Site Name - WordPress

Comment: Doesn't word. Still showing